# how to find missing number between minimum and maximum

Tags: numpy

I want to make a NumPy array which has below;

Random number: 0~9 (0<=value<=9) Random 1D size: 5~9 (5<= size <=9)

And I hope to find missing numbers between min and max so I made a code like this

```
import numpy as np

min_val = 0
max_val = 10
min_val_len = 5
max_val_len = 10
arr1 = [4,3,2,7,8,2,3]
a = list(arr1)
print(a)

diff = np.setdiff1d(range(min_val, max_val), arr1)
arr = np.arange(min_val_len, max_val_len)

if diff in arr:
    print(diff)
else:
    print("no missing")
```

In my purpose, the output will be [5,6].
And if an input is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], the result will be 'no_missing'.
But the code isn't work on my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you expect `in` to work in a way it does not: You want to check every single element, try:

```
b = [d in arr for d in diff]
```

Now `b` contains a boolean value for each value `d` of `diff`. If you want to find the actual number that are missing you can do it using a condition

```
b = np.intersect1d(np.setdiff1d(range(min_val, max_val), arr1), arr)
```

Also note that python has built in *set* types, so you do not actually need to use numpy.

Now `b` contains all numbers of `d` that are in `arr`. But you can do it in even a simpler way as you're already using the notion of sets:

```
print(np.setdiff1d(rang
```